# Prevent html comment tag autocomplete in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to disable autoclosing of html comment tags (

`<!--` gets completed with `-->` ) in VS Code (for mac).

I've already tried the following options, with no success :

- editor.autoclosingbrackets (->never)
- editor.autoclosingquotes (->never)
- editor.accept suggestion on commit character (->false)
- editor.accept suggestion on enter (->off)
- html.autoclosing tags (->off)
- html.format (->off)

Any other suggestions ? Thanks